# Configure Apache to use different Unix User Accounts (www-data) per Site

Tags: apache, unix, webserver, apache-config

An Apache 2.x Webserver with default configurations from the ubuntu/debian repositories will use the www-data unix account for apache2 processes handling web requests. Assuming that apache is serving two different sites (domain1.com and domain2.com), is it possible for apache to use unix user www-data1 when handling requests to domain1.com, and use unix user www-data2 when handling requests to domain2.com? The motivation is to isolate the code for each domain name from one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html).

Answer (score 1):

suPHP is also a nice thing to look into:

"suPHP is a tool for executing PHP scripts with the permissions of their owners. It consists of an Apache module (mod_suphp) and a setuid root binary (suphp) that is called by the Apache module to change the uid of the process executing the PHP interpreter."

-http://www.suphp.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache2-mpm-itk to achieve this.

You will be able to run each vhost using group and user of your choice.

Check this article for details:

http://www.howtoforge.com/running-vhosts-under-separate-uids-gids-with-apache2-mpm-itk-on-ubuntu-9.04

I used this on my development machine (Ubuntu), If you're using for production please read this page carefully:

http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/